How to make an element in a list as null
How to overwrite the value of banana to null
Input
{
  "fruits": [
    "apple",
    "banana",
    "cherry"
  ]
}

Desired Output:
{
  "fruits": ["apple", null, "cherry"]
}


You can use the conditional logic by separating the components of the array by the ones those are counterparts of banana vs. others within a shift transformation such as
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "fruits": {
        "*": {
          "banana": { "@": "&3[&2]" },
          "*": { "@1": "&3[&2]" }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]

the demo on the site https://jolt-demo.appspot.com/ is :

